# IIS Rewrite rule and going back to non secure http: afterwards

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5

I got a copy of an https rewrite rule so that when certain keywords are in the url it automatically redirects to an https: on a specific port.

However, I would also like something that when I want to logout of the secure area and go back to the non ssl site that it's no longer on https.   I have been unsucessful in doing this.

Can someone tell me what I need to do?
Here's the https rule I used.

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Secure Account Controller" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^account" ignoreCase="true" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true" >
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off"/>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="([^/:]*?):[^/]*?" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:1}:44300{URL}"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
   </rewrite>
```

** UPDATED ** 
This seems to have done it..  Not sure why the url in the browswer doesn't revert once it's finished.. but when I click on another page in the site... it's showing http

```
  <rule name="Home Controller" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^home" ignoreCase="true" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true" >
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on"/>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="([^/:]*?):[^/]*?" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://{C:1}:7224{URL}"/>
  </rule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- UPDATED ** This seems to have done it.. Not sure why the url in the browser doesn't revert once it's finished.. but when I click on another page in the site... it's showing http